# Apache log parser

Tags: apache-2.2

Does anyone have a script with awk that can be used for parsing through apache logs to return quick stats?

Comment: What stats do you want? # unique IPs?

Comment: Yes - but I don't keep them - I just write what I need at the time. Thats kind of the point of awk! For more general stuff I use awstats

Answer (score 0):

What kind of stats? Specify it.
You could take a look on `awstats`

Comment: As an example the log format used is as follows:

Comment: Based on the above format and example log, how can I find teh urls that are taking longer than n seconds. Say 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to generate random http stats, I usually install analog. http://www.analog.cx/ it's been around for over 15 years and can do simple or complex stuff, very efficiently.

"visitors" looks interesting, although I haven't tried it yet. http://www.hping.org/visitors/

Comment: I need some example awk scripts which I can use because I dont have the ability to install any software on the server.                       `LogFormat "%h|%{client-ip}i|%u|%t|%P|\"%r\"|\"%{Referer}i\"|s:%>s|%b|%T"`

Comment: Test log is as follows
10.10.10.1|172.10.10.1|-|[24/Mar/2011:18:43:18 -0400]|31597|"POST /someproxy/SomeServlet?to=http://domain/ab/api/som.ashx HTTP/1.1"|"http://somedomain/app/link/page.html?query=F"|s:200|2|15

Comment: You could install software, and copy logs, to another system (maybe a VM on your laptop or something).